# Regression and Covariance Parameter Matrices in Multiresponse Gaussian Regression Using glmnet (R)?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model

I am new to using glmnet. How do you extract the estimated (sparse) regression and covariance parameter matrices in multiresponse gaussian regression using the glmnet package? There doesn't seem to be clear indications in the package's vignette.

Thanks for your attention.

EDIT: Any suggestions of alternative packages with small examples are welcome.